# I can not turn off VoiceOver on iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone, voiceover, voice-control

**How can I turn off VoiceOver and get back to normal ?!**

As I follow the instructions how to turn off 'VoiceOver' in Setting on my iPhone,
however VoiceOver icon get back on quickly after double click...
(haven't upgrade iOS 8.1.1 yet)

- Tried to do double click 'Voiceover' icon in Setting, but doesn't off and switch on  back quickly..
- Done press 'Home' button 3 times quickly, but Top page shows up later..
- Done turn off the phone, the VoiceOver shows up with passcode screen..

What else I can do for turning off the annoying voice?

Comment: Also my iphone is using as prepaid.

Comment: I resolved this problem by Siri.

Comment: I commanded Siri to turn off Voiceover. Siri turned off it in 3 seconds!! She was useful.

Answer (score 2):

**Turning Voiceover Off**

1. Double-tap the Settings icon on your homepage.
2. Use three fingers to scroll down to the General menu, and double-click on it.
3. Use three fingers to scroll down to the Accessibility menu, and double-click on it.
4. Double-tap on the VoiceOver menu item.
5. Turn VoiceOver off

Alternatively, in iTunes you select summary and click Universal Access, then choose either Zoom or Neither rather than VoiceOver.

Comment: Actually, can't turn off Voiceover with double click. as I mentioned in Question...
I think I need a resolution in iTune then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem after my phone was reset.

It was fixed after I connected it with iTunes via my Computer, and loaded a backup.

In one way or another iTunes seem to be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My sin was exploring what this voice over toggle do... Then it turned the screen off!!! I started taking screen shots to know where I am .. Then I reset all settings.. The screen light cane back but the voice over still On!! Then I did it with SiRi ... Tried siri to close it and Siri did it.. Do not ask me how :-) ..After one full hour of total frustration..